# Get an object from a DomElement Node without frameworks

Tags: javascript, html, htmlelements

I have an element in my page:

```
<form>

<div data-id="x">
    <label>field 1</label>
    <input name="field1" type="text" value="Foo" />
    <label>field 2</label>
    <input name="field2" type="number" value="5" />
</div>

<div data-id="y">
    <label>field 1</label>
    <input name="field1" type="text" value="Foo" />
    <label>field 2</label>
    <input name="field2" type="number" value="5" />
</div>

...other 100 inputs...
</form>
```

I'm looking for a javascript script like that:

```
var theElement = document.querySelector('[data-id="x"]');
var myObject = theElement.toObject();
```

And the object must looks like

```
{"field1":"Foo","field2":5}
```

I can't use the `FormData` strategy because I need a very small set of data from a very big form, but it is like a "partial FormData".

I'm asking if exists a standard method to convert the content of an HTMLElement in an object like for the FormData.

PS: i can use also the data-attribute if necessary

Comment: And the problem is? Iterate over the `<input />` elements and create the object,. `.querySelectorAll()` and `.forEach()` from the `NodeList` will do the job.

Comment: If you use a form element you could use the `FormData` constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no standard quicky method to do this task.

The solution is iterate over inputs and selects:

```
<script>
  let myObj = {};
  let element = document.querySelector('[data-id="x"]');
  element.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(el=> {
     // check the type
     // the property is : el.name
     // the value must be : el.value for text/number/email...
     // the value for the type="checkbox" is according to checked attribute
  });
  element.querySelectorAll('select').forEach(sel=> {
      // if multiple choise => create an array of selected options
      // if single => check the selected option's value
  });

</script>
```

This is the code i've used (simplified)